# JMeter existing script does not work after migration from ADF 11gR1 to 12c

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I have a migrated ADF source from 11gR1 to 12c (12.2.1.3.0).

When i do load test using JMeter to create timesheet entries, I don't get 100% result.

```
**Request Records      Response Records**
5 records              5 records created.
6 records              6 records created.
7 records              3 to 5 records created.
100 records            60 to 70 records created.
```

The log file says "**The component is not registered for active data**". Even after providing ChangeEventPolicy property to None from ppr, I got the same result.

Modified the ChangeEventPolicy for that particular component and also for the iterator. Also I have changed my Application Module's connection pool properties.

Note: The load test works 100% for the original source (Jdev 11.1.1.3.0)

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the migration of Oracle ADF version has impacted some technical ids in pages that you need to correlate:

- some may have been removed
- some may have been renamed
- some may have been added (most probable hypothesis)

So you should record the initial scenarios and compare request/responses to find those ids and do the required correlation.

With any tool, reusing a script on an application without further checks is risky as :

- you may miss additional requests made
- you may have requests that have been removed
- some requests may have changed